# Connect to Cloudant CouchDB with Node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, couchdb, cloudant

I am trying to connect to my CouchDB database on Cloudant using Node.js.

This worked on the shell:

```
    curl https://weng:password@weng.cloudant.com/my_app/_all_docs
```

But this node.js code didn't work:

```
    var couchdb = http.createClient(443, 'weng:password@weng.cloudant.com', true);
    var request = couchdb.request('GET', '/my_app/_all_docs', {
        'Host': 'weng.cloudant.com'
    });
    request.end();
    request.on('response', function (response) {
        response.on('data', function (data) {
            util.print(data);
        });
    });
```

It gave me this data back:

```
    {"error":"unauthorized","reason":"_reader access is required for this request"}
```

How do I do to list all my databases with Node.js?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The built-in Node.js http client is pretty low level, it doesn't support HTTP Basic auth out of the box. The second argument to `http.createClient` is just a hostname. It doesn't expect credentials in there.

You have two options:

**1. Construct the HTTP Basic Authorization header yourself**

```
var Base64 = require('Base64');
var couchdb = http.createClient(443, 'weng.cloudant.com', true);
var request = couchdb.request('GET', '/my_app/_all_docs', {
    'Host': 'weng.cloudant.com',
    'Authorization': 'Basic ' + Base64.encode('weng:password')
});
request.end();
request.on('response', function (response) {
    response.on('data', function (data) {
        util.print(data);
    });
});
```

You will need a Base64 lib such as [one for node written in C](http://github.com/pkrumins/node-base64), or a pure-JS one (e.g. [the one that CouchDB Futon uses](http://cloudant.cloudant.com/_utils/script/base64.js)).

**2. Use a more high-level Node.js HTTP client**

A more featureful HTTP client, like [Restler](http://github.com/danwrong/restler), will make it much easier to do the request above, including credentials:

```
var restler = require('restler');
restler.get('https://weng.cloudant.com:443/my_app/_all_docs', {
    username: 'weng',
    password: 'password'
}).on('complete', function (data) {
    util.print(data);
});
```

Comment: Also, if you are calling this programmatically, you should create an API key. And give that key permissions to the database. Databases -> Docs (Pull-Down) -> Permissions. Add your key and give it 'Reader/Writer/etc...' access.

https://my_company.cloudant.com/dashboard.html#/database/my-database/permissions

Answer (score 7):

There are lots of CouchDB modules for Node.js.

- [node-couch](http://github.com/sixtus/node-couch/tree/master) - a CouchDB connector
- [node-couchdb](http://github.com/felixge/node-couchdb) - A full API implementation
- [node-couchdb-min](http://github.com/rsms/node-couchdb-min) - Light-weight client with low level of abstraction and connection pooling.
- [cradle](http://github.com/cloudhead/cradle) - a high-level, caching, CouchDB client

Comment: node-couchdb RE-update: now maintained & active has commits showing on may 12, 2012

Comment: [Cloudant's FAQ](https://cloudant.com/for-developers/faq/development/) _What library should I use for [insert_language_here]?_ also suggests [Sag](http://www.saggingcouch.com/), that is specifically tested against Cloudant

Answer (score 5):

Just wanted to add

- [nano](https://github.com/dscape/nano) - minimalistic couchdb driver for node.js

to the list. It is written by Nuno Job, CCO of [nodejitsu](https://www.nodejitsu.com/), and actively maintained.

Answer (score -1):

This answer is looking a bit dated. Here is an updated answer that I  verified using the following Cloudant Supported NPM Node Client library that works.
https://www.npmjs.com/package/cloudant#getting-started

And to answer his question on how to list his databases use the following code.

```
//Specify your Cloudant Database Connection URL. For Bluemix format is: https://username:password@xxxxxxxxx-bluemix.cloudant.com

dbCredentials_url = "https://username:password@xxxxxxxxx-bluemix.cloudant.com"; // Set this to your own account 

// Initialize the library with my account. 
// Load the Cloudant library. 
cloudant = require('cloudant')(dbCredentials_url);

// List the Cloudant databases
cloudant.db.list(function(err, allDbs) {
console.log('All my databases: %s', allDbs.join(', ')) });
```