# NodeJS and Cradle Not Connecting

Tags: javascript, node.js, cloudant, cradle

Using Cradle 5.5 and NodeJS 0.4.8, I can't seem to get a connection to work.  I've successfully used RESTLER, but I can't seem to configure cradle.  I'd like to take advantage of the caching aspects of Cradle.

I've tried both my Cloudant Account and a normal, admin party CouchDB database, both with the same results.

Admin Party Database:

`var conn1 = new (cradle.Connection)("XX.XX.XXX.XXX", 5984);`

Cloudant:

```
var account = {
    username: "user", 
    password: "pwd"
};
var conn = new (cradle.Connection)("user.cloudant.com", 443, {
    secure: true,
    auth: account
});
```

I've tried all combinations, nothing seems to get me anything other than undefined when I do things like `console.log(conn.config());` or `console.log(conn.databases());`

Any ideas on what might be causing this?  I am starting to think it might be the versions of Cradle/NodeJS, but I can't seem to find a reference to them to not working together anywhere.

**UPDATE:** Still having issues, but I changed the code a bit to see if I could pinpoint the problem.

```
cradle.setup({host:'username.cloudant.com', port: 443,
                auth: { username: 'username', password: 'password'},
                options: {secure: true, cache: true, raw: false}
});

c = new(cradle.Connection)().config();

console.log(c);

console.log(cradle);
```

My output is the following:

```
undefined

{ extend: [Function],

  Response: [Function: Response],

  Cache: [Function],

  host: 'username.cloudant.com',

  port: 443,

  auth: { username: 'username', password: 'password' },

  options: 

   { cache: true,

     raw: false,

     timeout: 0,

     secure: false,

     headers: {},

     host: 'username.cloudant.com',

     port: 443,

     auth: { username: 'username', password: 'password' },

     options: { secure: true, cache: true, raw: false } },

  setup: [Function],

  Connection: [Function: Connection],

  merge: [Function] }
```

I'm incredibly stumped-anyone else at least experienced this before?

Comment: same for me, I updated to NodeJS 0.4.9, but the result is the same.

Comment: Continue to try and get this to work with no luck.  I've successfully done this with RESTLER ie a lower-level connection, but can't seem to get cradle to work for me.  Is there any other information I can provide to better troubleshoot this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is working for me

Cradle: 0.5.5
Node: 0.5.0-pre

```
var cradle = require('cradle'),
    db;


db = new (cradle.Connection)("duncanm.cloudant.com", {auth:{username:"duncanm", password:"xxxxx"}}).database();
```

Duncan.

edit: connects, but I cant do anything.. this post has some useful information in it:
[Connect to Cloudant CouchDB with Node.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4070331/connect-to-cloudant-couchdb-with-node-js)